# Javascript test hashtable with key / value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a saved_tokens hashtable. I also have the key and the value. I would like to check the hashtable to see if the pair exist, if exist, do something. Thanks.

Code thus far

```
var saved_tokens = {}

//method
    _suggest: function( items, clientId ) {

        var filteredItems = [];

        $.each(items, function(i, item ) {
            if(saved_tokens.hasOwnProperty(clientId)) { 

                //need to test for item here
                if(item exist need help) {
                    filteredItems.push(item);
                }
            }
        }); 
   }
```

Comment: What does a token look like in your `saved_tokens` object?

Comment: @Joel Potter - I was trying to get it to look like this var hashtable = {};
hashtable['key1'] = 'value1';
hashtable['key2'] = 'value2';

Comment: But what is your key? Is clientId the key for the item you want to find?

Comment: ClientId is the key, item is the value. I just need to check the hash to see if the value exist. So basically if value exist where key is equal to clientId "key1" do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you what, but I assume that you are trying to get the `filteredItems` list based on the matched items b/w `items` list + `clientID` and `saved_tokens`.

Try,

```
_suggest: function( items, clientId ) {

        var filteredItems = [];

        $.each(items, function(i, item ) {
            if(saved_tokens.hasOwnProperty(clientId) &&
                         saved_tokens[clientID] === item) {
                    filteredItems.push(item);

                    //add a return false here to terminate the loop.
                }
            }
        }); 
   }
```